# Using Offline folders

Tags: windows-7

I am trying to setup offline files to a network drive at my company and would like for it sync up as soon as im connected to the network or VPN.  I am having trouble getting  my mapped network drive to always be available (via offline files).  It tells me it cannot setup offline files.  Is it not possible to make a mapped network drive available online?

I am using Windows 7 Professional

Steps taken:

1. Go to computer
2. Right click the mapped network drive on the bottom
3. Go to properties
4. Offline Files
5. Put a check in Always available offline
6. Next thing that happens is when it tells me it cant be used for offline files

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you'll have to log into the server hosting the share and enable it there, not on the end PC.

Windows 7: Right click on folder > properties > sharing > advanced sharing > caching

2003: right click on folder > sharing and security > caching

2008 R2: Same as windows 7

[image: Steps]

Comment: I will give that try in a few minutes and report back.

Comment: I do not see the option on the server level to turn on offline files for that specific folder.  Do you know why that is?

Comment: Are you doing it on the share or on the folder of the share?

Comment: Folder in the share, but to access that folder, I need to have the share available offline first.

Comment: You have to do it on the machine hosting the shares, as if you're actually sitting there. C:\blah you can't do it through \\share\blah. If you're not the administrator for that server you might have to ask them to do it for you, or they may have offline files disabled.

Comment: I am an administrator, ill check to see if offline files are disabled or not.

Comment: It was disabled, I enabled it but when I right click the folder on the server, the offline files tab is still not there.  Will the server require a reboot?

Comment: I modified my original questions with the steps to get to the offline/caching settings. Is the share on Windows 7 professional? Also are you sure there aren't any group policies effecting offline files? I know there are settings that disable parts of it.

Comment: The share is on Server 2008 Standard and I want to make it view able offline on a Win 7 Pro laptop.  And yes, no group policies.

Comment: If that "Caching" button isn't there I don't know what to tell you. What options do you see?

Comment: Glad you figured it out.